# I there a way to run multiple worker in WSL2

Tags: laravel-6.2

I am running laravel in WSL2 and testing worker with

```
php artisan queue:work --timeout=0
```

it  only run single worker,
I am trying to replicate the production server with 30 workers in it

is there a way that I can run multiple of this on WSL2?